# Testing custom events react-native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am using Jest and Enzyme for my tests. I have no problem testing normal events but I am struggling to find the correct approach for how to trigger and test events within components that come from Native Modules. In my Jest setup I have the following:

```
jest.mock('NativeEventEmitter', () => class MockNativeEventEmitter{
  addListener = () => jest.fn()
  removeListener = () => jest.fn()
  removeAllListeners = () => jest.fn()
});
```

However, I am not sure within the test how I go about actually dispatching an event. So, for example I have a Native module for when the user shakes the device. Within the component itself this is setup like so:

```
shakeEvents: ['shaken],
deviceShakeEmitter: {},

componentDidMount() {
  this.deviceShakeEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(Shake)
  this.deviceShakeEmitter.addListener('shaken', this['shaken'])
 },
```

I know for inbuilt events i can use jest.simulate('press') etc, but for the custom event I am struggling to understand how I approach this within the tests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wanted to do this as well, and I managed to find the solution in the react-native Github repo. They use the normal JS EventEmitter to mock NativeEventEmitter:

```
const EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
const RCTDeviceEventEmitter = require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter');

/**
 * Mock the NativeEventEmitter as a normal JS EventEmitter.
 */
class NativeEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super(RCTDeviceEventEmitter.sharedSubscriber);
  }
}
```

Now you just need to setup the mock, and instantiate this emitter to send out any event you like:

```
jest.mock('NativeEventEmitter');

const nativeEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
nativeEmitter.emit('SomeEventYouListenTo');
```

Comment: I just went through the react-native source code to find out more about NativeEventEmitter

Comment: Is it possible one of the OPs or someone else explain to me a bit more? Where does the mock go? jest setup file?

Comment: @JanithaR I just create a folder in which I add a file for each mocked service. Simply import it in your test file and instantiate. No magic here.